# Copy sheets and point its links to itself?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I am copying several worksheets from one workbook to another.  The first sheet contains some data that all the other sheets link to from text boxes using a formula something like this: ='Cover Sheet'!A2

However, the new document changes the formula to maintain its link to the original workbook, and adds a file reference: ='C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp[tmpD474.tmp]Cover Sheet'!A4

Is it possible to have it copy the formulas literally so that they point to the new workbook's Cover Sheet?  If not, then I have a completely different question: how do you change the contents of an Excel text box using c# interop?

Comment: can you not put the sheets with the formulas in, in a seperate workbook and then copy data into that workbook? I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to replicate the behaviour with a workbook and some ActiveX textboxes...weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to changed the contents of a text box.  First you have to name the text box in Excel, then get the call [Worksheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheet.aspx).[Shapes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shapes.item.aspx).Item("") to get the TextBox as a [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.shape.aspx) object, then modify the text by setting the [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.textbox.aspx).TextFrame.Characters.Text property.